# iOS NSMutableArray suddenly obtains more values

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, detailview

I'm loading data (json) from a backend into my UITableView - so far so good.
Data will be passed to to a DetailView after the user selected a specific row - works fine.

BUT...when I return to the UITableView from the DetailView suddenly the Array, which obtains different IDs, contains more values:

So I'm saving each ID in the NSMutableArray like this:

```
//Dictionary
NSDictionary *GroupDataDictionary = [self.groupDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//save groupID to array atIndex: current indexPath.row
[self.groupIDArray insertObject:[GroupDataDictionary valueForKey:@"id"] atIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This works fine. I implemented a test to display each GroupID saved in the NSMutableArray

```
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 2
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 3
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 4
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 5
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 6
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 7
```

But the thirdtime I return from the DetailView to my TableView I'll get something like this:

```
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 2
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 2
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 3
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 4
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 5
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 6
GroupID in NSMutableArray : 7
```

This goes on like this until the complete Array contains ID 2.

What is going on?

Thx for help!

Comment: Some other part of your code is likely writing that array. You need to show more code, or look for the code that changes the array. It is probably going to be a tricky find, because the array does not have its own name, only a position inside the mutable dictionary. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I'm loading the data in the "viewDidLoad" Method.
The GroupID is added to the array in the "tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath" - Method. I think it has to do something with this...(?)

Comment: Yes, most definitely! `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not supposed to write anything anywhere. If you find a need to alter any data structure not local to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method inside the method's implementation, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix it and try again!